# Цветная линия css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть цветная полоса, есть ли вариант укротить код, сильно громоздко и не совсем удобно получилось. И что можно сделать что бы при адаптации, часть цветов скрывалось или более менее оставалась при своих габаритах.

```css
.orange, .purple, .blue, .pink, .yellow, .green{
    width:calc(100% / 24);
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
}
.orange{
    background: #ee6a51;
}
.purple{
    background: #a883b9;
}
.pink{
    background: #eb649f;
}
.blue{
    background: #00b6ef;
}
.yellow{
    background: #ffd749;
}
.green{
    background: #abc933;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorLine">
    <span class="orange"></span>
    <span class="purple"></span>
    <span class="pink"></span>
    <span class="blue"></span>
    <span class="yellow"></span>
    <span class="green"></span>
    <span class="orange"></span>
    <span class="purple"></span>
    <span class="pink"></span>
    <span class="blue"></span>
    <span class="yellow"></span>
    <span class="green"></span>
    <span class="orange"></span>
    <span class="purple"></span>
    <span class="pink"></span>
    <span class="blue"></span>
    <span class="yellow"></span>
    <span class="green"></span>
    <span class="orange"></span>
    <span class="purple"></span>
    <span class="pink"></span>
    <span class="blue"></span>
    <span class="yellow"></span>
    <span class="green"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Совсем ничего не понятно, CSS получился совсем не громоздким, html построен по тому что нужно. Что ты понимаешь под "при адаптации, часть цветов скрывалось или более менее оставалась при своих габарита" в твоем примере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так годится?

```css
.color-line {
  height: 20px;
  
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
    #ee6a51   0  ,   #ee6a51  20px,
    #a883b9  20px,   #a883b9  40px,
    #eb649f  40px,   #eb649f  60px,
    #00b6ef  60px,   #00b6ef  80px,
    #ffd749  80px,   #ffd749 100px,
    #abc933 100px,   #abc933 120px
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="color-line"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно и без JavaScript  и одним элементом (используя CSS3):

```css
.colorLine {
    background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #ee6a51, #ee6a51 4.17%, #a883b9 4.17%, #a883b9 8.33%, #eb649f 8.33%, #eb649f 12.5%, #00b6ef 12.5%, #00b6ef 16.67%, #ffd749 16.67%, #ffd749 20.83%, #abc933 20.83%, #abc933 25%);
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #ee6a51, #ee6a51 4.17%, #a883b9 4.17%, #a883b9 8.33%, #eb649f 8.33%, #eb649f 12.5%, #00b6ef 12.5%, #00b6ef 16.67%, #ffd749 16.67%, #ffd749 20.83%, #abc933 20.83%, #abc933 25%);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #ee6a51, #ee6a51 4.17%, #a883b9 4.17%, #a883b9 8.33%, #eb649f 8.33%, #eb649f 12.5%, #00b6ef 12.5%, #00b6ef 16.67%, #ffd749 16.67%, #ffd749 20.83%, #abc933 20.83%, #abc933 25%);
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorLine"></div>
```

См. [repeating-linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient)

PS. Не работает в старых IE!

Comment: цвет указывается в процентах, если у меня будет 6 разных цветов и каждый цвет  5%, на ПК будет хорошо, а вот с мобильными будет беда, хотелось бы не использовать "@media"

Comment: Сделайте фиксированную ширину полосок.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы блоки оставались при своих габаритах, их нужно зафиксировать. А если нужно прятать блоки при изменении размера блока, то проще всего его перестраивать. Может так?

```
<div class="colorLine"></div>


.colorLine span {
    width: 50px;
      height: 20px;
      float: left;
}
.orange{
    background: #ee6a51;
}
.purple{
    background: #a883b9;
}
.pink{
    background: #eb649f;
}
.blue{
    background: #00b6ef;
}
.yellow{
    background: #ffd749;
}
.green{
    background: #abc933;
}


var colors = ['orange', 'purple', 'pink', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green'];
var blockWidth = 50;
var init = function () {
        $('.colorLine').empty();
        for (var i=0; i<$('.colorLine').first().width()-blockWidth-1; i+=blockWidth) {
        $('.colorLine').append("<span class="+colors[(i/blockWidth) % colors.length]+"></span>");
    } 
};
$(window).resize(init);
init();
```

Comment: Все хорошо, но нужно что бы на всю ширину было, а так до 50px пустоты

Comment: Для такого случая можно немного доработать функцию
  `var init = function () {
var width = $('.colorLine').first().width();
  $('.colorLine').empty();
  for (var i=0; i<width; i+=blockWidth) {
      $('.colorLine').append("<span class="+colors[(i/blockWidth) % colors.length]+"></span>");
      if (width - blockWidth < i) {
          $('.colorLine').children().last().css('width', (width - i) + 'px');
        }
    }
}; `

Comment: отлично, спасибо, правда только почему то на одну линию действует, если две или более, то только на последнюю

Comment: Потому что для нескольких нужно циклом перебирать
`var init = function () {
  var width = $('.colorLine').first().width();
  $('.colorLine').empty();
  for (var i=0; i<width; i+=blockWidth) {
      $('.colorLine').append("<span class="+colors[(i/blockWidth) % colors.length]+"></span>");
      if (width - blockWidth < i) {
          $('.colorLine').each(function(){
              $(this).children().last().css('width', (width - i) + 'px');
            });
        }
    } 
};`